# trying to autoincrement primarykey using trigger in flask and storing in sqlplus oracle 10g

Tags: database, flask, triggers, sqlplus, auto-increment

```
'''@app.route("/indexf",methods=["POST","GET"])
def signup():
     conn=cx_Oracle.connect(user="SYSTEM",password="bnm")
     cur= conn.cursor()
     a1=""""create sequence fid_seq"""
     ass=""" create trigger tfarmer
          before insert on farmeruser
           for each row
           begin
           select fid_seq.nextval
          into :new.fid
           from dual
           end;
           /"""
     
   
     
     if request.method == "POST":
            
            fname=request.form.get('fname')
            email=request.form.get('email')
            password=request.form.get('password')
           
            
          
            encpassword=generate_password_hash(password)
            

         
            execute="""INSERT INTO farmeruser VALUES (:fid,:fname,:email,:password)"""
            cur.execute(execute, {'fid':fid,'fname':fname, 'email':email, 'password':encpassword})
     
            conn.commit()

     return render_template('indexf.html') 
'''
```

here i am trying to get fname,email,password from user and autoincrement fid which is primary key using triggers .but i dont know how to pass fid in flask to autoincrement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. 10g, really? Are you working for a museum? :-) Current production version is 19c, 10g is 20 years old ... Sorry for the cheap joke.

So your trigger works, if you want to set the value for fid explicitly (this is how I understand your question) you must change the trigger:

```
...
begin
IF :new.fid IS NULL THEN
   SELECT fid_seq.nextval INTO :new.fid FROM dual;
   END IF;
END;
```

If you decide to change to a more recent Oracle version you can do

```
:new.fid:= fid_seq.nextval;
```

instead of the SELECT statement.

Comment: yeah thanks for the reply...even ik oracle 10g is older version but cant help have to use we are supposed to follow what college says .i am able to auto increment fid using sql terminal but the problem arises when i try to insert using flask it directly stores null value as fid .what should i make changes please do reply as soon as possible

Comment: Did you try to change the trigger as I showed? This should prevent every tool from inserting null